# How to sort a 2D array of complex numbers against the real part of the first?

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array, complex-numbers

I have a simple question about sorting. I have a 2D array with complex numbers like this one

```
[[(-110.61040004379576-17.354473737234287j), (634.2701711342786+20.835585013392976j)],
 [(-56.513088619798417+19.304564206160592j), (139.27388305766863+22.035225424174627j)], 
 [(-56.107824445301581-15.926033069760162j), (139.59169287146287+21.499544204724476j)], 
 [(45.747228005094165-13.96425461096984j), (92.707153363055141-12.92524051712571j)], 
 [(-111.22348501455198-15.926033038872692j), (84.47603226469721+21.499544215863018j)], 
 [(45.747228023236914-13.964254617324347j), (92.707153338674217-12.925240518653737j)], 
 [(-56.107824379236632-15.926033025484159j), (139.59169284624946+21.499544241697734j)], 
 [(-111.62498538487328-18.53021375196538j), (138.66271112979905+18.818585903566003j)], 
 [(-56.107824363639025-15.926033025268273j), (139.59169284605719+21.499544250473367j)], 
 [(45.747228053266504-13.964254607367101j), (92.707153308435764-12.925240545154857j)]]
```

and I would like to sort it against the real part of the first complex number. I tried the 
`.sort(key=lambda x: x[0].real)` but it answers None. Any bright ideas ? Thanks for helping.

R.

Answer (score 6):

You've got `None` because `sort` method doesn't return anything, but sort list in-place. So, if you want to create a separate sorted list, you can use [sorted](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=sort#sorted) function, for example: `sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0].real)`. Or you can use your already sorted list after calling `sort` method.

Comment: @RolandGuichard You can accept the answer if it solved your problem.